# How to set ConnectionString configuration for Azure App Service in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying a website written in Asp.Net Core 2.2 which has a connection to an Azure Sql Database. Where do I set the Connection String in the **Azure App Service deploy** task in **Azure DevOps**?

In my WebApp, the `DefaultConnection` is in `appsettings.json` which works fine locally. I want to override this when deployed to Azure.

I tried setting `-DefaultConnection $(DefaultConnection)` in the **Application and Configuration Settings** section of the **Azure App Service deploy** task but the Connection String did not get set. The value is in a variable in Azure DevOps.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Put the connection string in a key vault. Retrieve the connection string from the key vault at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

There is a new preview task `Azure App Service Setting` can help you with.
[image]

You can refer to this [Deploy Connection Strings using Azure App Service Deploy #9017](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9017#issuecomment-556936128)

Answer (score 2):

It may need you define the value of `ConnectionString` in the Azure app service.

[image: ConnectionString in Azure]

This could not be configured in Variables if you want to set it in Configuration setting.

Comment: Adding the connection string there does not fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The parameter name used in the deployment should be `ConnectionStrings_DefaultConnectionString` as the appsettings.json uses this hierarchy for connection strings.

i.e. `-ConnectionStrings_DefaultConnectionString $(DefaultConnection)`

Comment: Didn't work when I tried it , ended up with an AppSetting with the underscore in the name

Comment: Usually, setting nested variables like this [requires a double-underscore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal). Regardless, this method doesn't work.

Answer (score -5):

change it in appsettings.json , it should work